# How to use cordova-plugin-video-trim

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am building a video sharing app with ionic.
I want when users wants to upload videos and it will give them a preview where they can trim the video, now I found the Cordova plugin that can do it, but I don't knowhow to use it
Here is the plugin

`cordova-plugin-video-trim` from `https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-video-trim`

Now please, how can I use this plugin in my ionic application

Comment: your question is sooooooo generic. I answered your question but try to be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the project root and run these commands:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-video-trim
```

Then run:

```
npm i cordova-plugin-video-trim
```

Then open your app.module.ts and import it and put it in providers:

```
import {YourPlugin} from './path-to-your-plugin-in-node_modules';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    YourPlugin
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

and now you can import it in your component controller (.page.ts file) and make an instance of it in the constructor and use its methods:

```
import {YourPlugin} from './path-to-your-plugin-in-node_modules';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-somepage',
  templateUrl: './somepage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./somepage.page.scss'],
})
export class SomepagePage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private plugin: YourPlugin) {
  }
}
```