# how to play audio on screen lock/background mode

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, audio, ionic3

im having issue with playing audio in ios device  with my ionic 3 app.when i lock the device or moves to background the audio playing for 15 to 20 seconds and getting stopped. i tried with enabling background mode and settings in xcode.nothing is working

```
 platform.ready().then(() => {

      if (platform.is('cordova')){

        //Subscribe on pause i.e. background
        this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
          console.log("background");
          this.bg.enable();

        });

        //Subscribe on resume i.e. foreground
        this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
          console.log("foreground");
          this.bg.disable();

        });
      }
    });
```

this is how i'm doing the background enable in player.ts file.[image]
this is xcode capabilites settings.
 this issue not producing in andorid

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Darshana, Sorry for the late response...i didnt find any solution for this, since the client requirement changed we developed our own player which doesnt care about app status any more.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If possible can you let me know how did you created you own player using ionic?

Comment: Checkout these, https://auth0.com/blog/building-an-audio-player-app-with-ionic-angular-rxjs-and-ngrx/
 https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-music-player-interface-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Can you let me know whether this code works for you in background mode ?

Comment: Yes It will work, you can check the app which i did intergrated this.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionic.jolaali ... go as guest and access free trail section.as per client requirement we didnt implemenetd any controls on lock screen, but you can see that the story is able to play in back ground mode.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The link which you provided https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-music-player-interface-in-ionic-2/ is related to Interface of player, sorry but I did not get solution to play audio in background in provided tutorial if possible can you please elaborate more on playing audio in background related code?

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/building-an-audio-player-app-with-ionic-angular-rxjs-and-ngrx/

which version of ionic you needed?

Comment: I am using Ionic version 5 and one more thing there is an issue in iOS devices, in android it works fine.

Comment: cool, May i know the iOS issue.

Comment: Audio background play is not working in iOS devices.

Comment: not at all working or its stopping after few second?

Comment: it is stopping after few second and next audio is not playing.

Comment: https://github.com/EinfachHans/cordova-plugin-advanced-background-mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240818/discussion-between-darshana-and-sa-e-chowdary).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is here: [Background Mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode)

this plugin is created just for this cause. if you don't know how to install and use plugins in ionic, check this out: [How to use this cordova plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184451/how-to-use-this-cordova-plugin/62185527#62185527)

Comment: I hope you understand my question clearly. yes i did installed background mode plugin and using the same when the app goes background as you can see in the code attached.